# Traveling through the DOM from child to nephew in css

Tags: html, css, dom, selector

How can you travel between  child of a particular element to the child of his sibling element it is necessary to go back to the father, namely to reach nephew
But how?

The constraint is to start with one of the children(to see if he checked), I try to build a game that has to check whether all the input element pressed in a certain line.

lets say i have that structure and i want to find out if all input are clicked :

```
<table>
 <tr class="cell1">
    <td class="cell" >
     <input  id="c1" type="checkbox"   name="c1"  value="">
     <label class="cell" for="c1"></label>
     </td>
    <td class="cell">
     <input  id="c2" type="checkbox"   name="c1"  value="">
     <label class="cell" for="c2"></label>
    </td>
    <td class="cell">
     <input  id="c3" type="checkbox"   name="c1"  value="">
     <label class="cell" for="c3"></label>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's [not currently possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) to get the parent of an element using a CSS selector, but you could get cousin elements using JavaScript if you were so inclined. Let's say the original element is `el`.

You could get to a cousin of `el` by doing this:

```
el.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[x].getElementsByTagName(el.tagName)[0];
```

... where `x` is the `td` element number you want. It sounds like you will want to write a loop over all of them.

Comment: This is a css question, not a javascript question.

Comment: @TinyGiant I must have hallucinated a JavaScript tag in the question. Going to agree with your close vote then.

Comment: i can use only pure css.

Comment: @OferEran Then not possible sorry, see duplicate.